# How can I create a view with a mixture of Text and TextFields dynamically in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, mobile-development

The issue I am encountering is, I need to be able to create a view in SwiftUI that looks like a sentence of text but has blanks where the user can enter their own text. I also need a way to be able to capture the entered text from the binding, but not sure how to do multiple bindings in a loop.

Ive tried a few options and the closest I have got is using LazyGrid, but it doesn't look like a normal sentence due to spacing?

```
struct MultiText: View {
    @State var text = "There was once a {-} that only had {-} in it. How did they get in? {-}"

    @State var answerText: String = "XXXXXXX"

    let rows = [
        GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 80))
    ]

    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: rows, spacing: 0, alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(text.components(separatedBy: " "), id: \.self) { component in
                if component == "{-}" {
                    TextField("", text: $answerText
                    )
                } else {
                    Text(component)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the following result

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMIMT.png)

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think can help use appropriate id's in ForEach:

```
    import SwiftUI
    
    struct Item: Identifiable {
        var id = UUID()
        var value: String
    }
    
    struct MultiText: View {
        @State var text = "There was once a {-} that only had {-} in it. How did they get in? {-}"
    
        @State var answerText: String = "XXXXXXX"
    
        let rows = [
            GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 80))
        ]
    
        var body: some View {
            LazyVGrid(columns: rows, alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(text.components(separatedBy: " ").map{Item(value: $0)}, id: \.id) { component in
                    if component.value == "{-}" {
                        TextField("", text: $answerText
                        )
                    } else {
                        Text(component.value)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

}
```

In this way you have multiple TextField.

I think also this can help:

[similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62334678/dynamic-textfields-based-on-user-input-using-swiftui)